# How to loop through values for if SUMIFS and COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, for-loop, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm working with Excel in Office 365.

Here are some example data:

Column A (Type):  1, 5, 3, 3, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, ...

Column B (Value): 15, 23, 14, 20, 17, 32, 11, 10, 9, 11, ...

Now, I can get the sum of values for the type 2s, say, with =SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, "=2").  But is there a way to do this for each type (i.e., for the type 1s all the way through the type 6s) without manually repeating the formula?  I'm not sure whether it's possible to implement something like a for-loop.

I tried just entering

```
=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, "=1"),
```

and

```
=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, "=2")
```

in the next row and dragging down.  Unfortunately, no matter how many I tried, it just repeated the cycle.  That is, "=1", "=2", "=3", "=1", "=2", "=3", and so on.  I want "=1", "=2", "=3", "=4",...

N.B.:  I am not allowed to use Pivot Tables for this.

Comment: You could use a Pivot Table

Comment: Typically you would use something like `ROW(1:1)` to represent `1`. When dragged down it grows until the sixth formula uses `ROW(6:6)` which equals `6`.

Comment: @Jeeped, I'm sorry, but I'm not well versed in Excel... I've always used other programs.  How would I incorporate ROW into my formula?

Comment: `=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, ROW(1:1))` and drag down or `=SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, COLUMN(A:A))` and drag right.

Comment: @Jeeped.  You've saved me, my friend.  So I can justify having used this little trick, it imposes the condition that the number in column A be equal to whatever number is specified within ROW?  Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

*Also by suggestion of @Jeeped*

---

Use this if you want to drag *down*

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,ROW(1:1))
```

And this if you want to drag *across*

```
=SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,COLUMN(A:A))
```

Comment: Go ahead and add the `COLUMN(A:A)` to drag right if you wish.

Comment: Nice addition, thanks :)